# Send just a warning on assertion fail

Tags: java, spring, testing

I have an integration test which is dependent on an external API. It is quite weird, because it does not always pass.

It goes something like this:

1. In the test I send a request to my API's endpoint.
2. There's some logic going on within my application (for example database insertions).
3. At last, before returning a response, there's a async call to external API.

Waiting for external API's response sometimes takes 500ms, but may as well take 8 seconds. I use Awaitality to wait until the response comes in, but it just makes my tests execute even 2 minutes longer (I have several test cases).

What I'd like to achieve is something like that: test waits 1 second for the response. If it does not come up within that period, then show some-kind-of warning (preferably to console). Also, do not let this test case fail because the response was not present, let this test pass.

Here's how I wait for the response.

```
await().atMost(UNTIL, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .pollInterval(ONE_REQUEST_PER, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .until(() -> // logic that acquires the response);
```

If the condition within `.until` is not fulfilled within some time, then test case is failed. I'd rather - as explained - have it send a warning to the console, not fail the test.

NOTE: I do not want to mock the API's response.

Comment: mock the call instead of "hoping it'll work out"

Comment: @Stultuske Hi, I've forgotten to include in the original post that I do not want to mock anything here. Would you still have any suggestions?

Comment: if an exception is thrown, catch it in your test, remove your assertions, ... This would, however, render your test pretty pointless

Comment: Use a try-catch-block in your test?

Comment: @Stultuske @Jens yes, obviously try-catch would work, but a simple `System.out.println` within the catch block would not render any big warning. So, I would not know immedietaly that the response did not come in. I'd have to go into raport and see each test case if it contains any message sent by `System.out.println`.